# Django - In a ModelForm, display data coming from a model linked with M2M relationship

Tags: django, forms, many-to-many

I would like to add information in a form, coming from the model linked with a M2M relationship to the model I'm updating.The form works properly, but I'm not able to add any information.
Here is what I get:
[image]

Here is the expected result:
[image]

**My solution**: finally, I updated `__str__()` mthod in `UserGroup` model to display what I expect (but, at this stage, [I lost the dynamic part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70145103/django-form-display-m2m-choices-in-multiselect-check-boxes-list) and my view does not work anymore :-/)

The main model is `Event` and it's linked to `Groups` thanks to this relationship; in the form, all groups are listed and displayed with checkboxes, but I'm only able to display the groups' name, no other information.

It looks like I miss some data / information: the group name is displayed only because I use `{{grp}}}` (see below) but it has no attribute / filed available, even if it is initialized with a query from the group model.
I envisaged a workaround (see below) because my first tries made me consider this kind of solution, but I'm not able to reproduce what I did :-/
Any idea of what I did wrong, or any advice to manage this? Thanks in advance.

Here are related code parts.
Models:

```py
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="société"
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(UserComp, verbose_name="utilisateurs", blank=True)
    group_name = models.CharField("nom", max_length=100)
    weight = models.IntegerField("poids", default=0)
    hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name

class Event(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="société"
    )
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(UserGroup, verbose_name="groupes", blank=True)
    rules = [("MAJ", "Majorité"), ("PROP", "Proportionnelle")]
    event_name = models.CharField("nom", max_length=200)
    event_date = models.DateField("date de l'événement")
    slug = models.SlugField()
    current = models.BooleanField("en cours", default=False)
    quorum = models.IntegerField(default=33)
    rule = models.CharField(
        "mode de scrutin", max_length=5, choices=rules, default="MAJ"
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Evénement"
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["company_id", "slug"], name="unique_event_slug")
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_name
```

Form:

```py
class EventDetail(forms.ModelForm):
    groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label = "Liste des groupes",
        queryset = None,
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required = False
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['event_name', 'event_date', 'quorum', 'rule', 'groups']


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
        self.fields['groups'].queryset= UserGroup.objects.\
                                                filter(company=instance.company).\
                                                order_by('group_name')
```

View:

```py
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser or (u.id is not None and u.usercomp.is_admin))
def adm_event_detail(request, comp_slug, evt_id=0):
    '''
        Manage events creation and options
    '''
    company = Company.get_company(request.session['comp_slug'])
    # all_groups = list(UserGroup.objects.filter(company=company, hidden=False).order_by('group_name').values())

    if evt_id > 0:
        current_event = Event.objects.get(id=evt_id)
        event_form = EventDetail(request.POST or None, instance=current_event)

    else:
        event_form = EventDetail(request.POST or None)

    event_form.fields['groups'].queryset = UserGroup.objects.\
                                                        filter(company=company, hidden=False).\
                                                        order_by('group_name')
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if event_form.is_valid():
            if evt_id == 0:
                # Create new event
                event_data = {
                    "company": company,
                    "groups": event_form.cleaned_data["groups"],
                    "event_name": event_form.cleaned_data["event_name"],
                    "event_date": event_form.cleaned_data["event_date"],
                    "quorum": event_form.cleaned_data["quorum"],
                    "rule":event_form.cleaned_data["rule"]
                }
                new_event = Event.create_event(event_data)
            else:
                new_event = event_form.save()

        else:
            print("****** FORMULAIRE NON VALIDE *******")
            print(event_form.errors)

    return render(request, "polls/adm_event_detail.html", locals())
```

HTML (I did not put each parts of the 'accordion' widget, I do not think they have anything to do with the problem):

```html
{% if evt_id %}
<form action="{% url 'polls:adm_event_detail' company.comp_slug evt_id %}" method="post">
{% else %}
<form action="{% url 'polls:adm_create_event' company.comp_slug %}" method="post">
{% endif %}
    {% csrf_token %}

    <!-- Hidden field where the referer is identified to go back to the related page after validation -->
    <input type="hidden" name="url_dest" value="{{ url_dest }}" />

    <br>

    <!-- Accordion -->
    <div id="eventDetails" class="accordion shadow">

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-white shadow-sm border-0">
                <h6 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold">
                    Evénement
                </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body p-5">
                <p>Nom : {{event_form.event_name}} </p>
                <p>Date : {{event_form.event_date}} </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Accordion item 2 - Event's groups -->
        <div class="card">
        <div id="headingTwo" class="card-header bg-white shadow-sm border-0">
            <h6 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" class="d-block position-relative collapsed text-dark collapsible-link py-2">
                    Groupes d'utilisateurs
                </a>
            </h6>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#eventDetails" class="collapse show">
            <div class="card-body p-5">
                <p>Sélectionnez le(s) groupe(s) d'utilisateurs participants à l'événement :</p>
                <ul>
                {% for grp in event_form.groups %}
                    <li>{{ grp }}
                        {{ grp.weight }}
                        {{ grp.hidden }}
                        {{ grp.nb_users }}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>

                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- Accordion end -->


    <button class="btn btn-success mt-5" type="submit">{% if evt_id %}Mettre à jour{% else %}Créer{% endif %}</button>
    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
    <a class="btn btn-secondary back_btn mt-5" href="*">Annuler</a>
    <div class="row">
        <div hidden>
            <!-- List of groups in event -->
            {{ event_form.group_list }}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Workaround**
If it's not possible to achieve this directly, I thought to a workaround that would be implemented in several parts:

- Create a list almost like the queryset: `group_list = UserGroup.objects.filter(company=instance.company).order_by('group_name').values()`
  I already know I can display each group with its details and a checkbox
- on client side (javascript), I manage an hidden list that would be part of the form, with the ID of each selected group. That means that the list will be dynamically updated when a box is checked on unchecked
- on the POST request, read the list to update the group attribute of updated event.

I would have prefered the users actions having effect directly to the form, but I know this could work

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing the form's groups field, not the model instance. The form field doesn't have any relationship to other models, it's just a field. You can access the underlying instance of the model form using `form.instance`.

Also note that you get a relationship manager object when querying related models. Hence, use `.all` to query all groups.

Try

```
     <ul>
         {% for grp in event_form.instance.groups.all %}
             <li>{{ grp }}
                 {{ grp.weight }}
                 {{ grp.hidden }}
                 {{ grp.nb_users }}
                </li>
         {% endfor %}
     </ul>
```

Comment: Yes it displays properties correctly! I did not know this syntax. But I do not have checkboxes anymore :-/

Comment: @Christophe, do you want to have checkboxes in front of group attributes? If you want to submit those data as part of the form, you need to set up a different form. Those are attributes of the UserGroup model, but your form is an Event modelform.

Comment: Yes, I would like this list being part of the form but display attributes in addition to the names to give information to ease the choice.
Actually, I managed to display the checkboxes + detailed information thanks to a list, but I cannot use it within  the form, and as far as possible I would like to avoid having both, manage the form field with js according to user's actions on the list...

Comment: Finally I updated the `__str__()` method in my `UserGroup` model