# Django form - Display M2M choices in multiselect check boxes' list

Tags: python, django, checkbox, django-forms, many-to-many

I'm trying to set up check boxes in a form to populate a field linked to another model with M2M relationship.
I used to managed this but made a lot of tests [to display additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70116613/django-in-a-modelform-display-data-coming-from-a-model-linked-with-m2m-relati), and now that I chose a solution (bases on my model's `__str__()` method), I'm not able anymore to display a list of all groups where those already linked to my event are checked.
Again, probably a very small detail I missed, but I do not see anything and I would appreciate some help.

Some pieces of code at this stage.

Models:

```py
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="société"
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(UserComp, verbose_name="utilisateurs", blank=True)
    group_name = models.CharField("nom", max_length=100)
    weight = models.IntegerField("poids", default=0)
    hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def nb_users(self):
        return UserComp.objects.filter(usergroup=self).count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name + " (Poids : " + str(self.weight) + " / " + str(self.nb_users) + " utilisateurs)"

class Event(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="société"
    )
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(UserGroup, verbose_name="groupes", blank=True)
    rules = [("MAJ", "Majorité"), ("PROP", "Proportionnelle")]
    event_name = models.CharField("nom", max_length=200)
    event_date = models.DateField("date de l'événement")
    slug = models.SlugField()
    current = models.BooleanField("en cours", default=False)
    quorum = models.IntegerField(default=33)
    rule = models.CharField(
        "mode de scrutin", max_length=5, choices=rules, default="MAJ"
    )

    class Meta:
        # Constraint(s) : an event_slug can be linked to only one company
        #       This allow several companies to use the same event_slugs,
        #       unless one sngle event_slug is used by company
        verbose_name = "Evénement"
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["company_id", "slug"], name="unique_event_slug")
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_name
```

Form (I'm quite sure I already had this `__init__()` method in my first working tests):

```py
class EventDetail(forms.ModelForm):
    groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label = "Liste des groupes",
        queryset = None,
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required = False
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['event_name', 'event_date', 'quorum', 'rule']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
        self.fields['groups'].queryset= UserGroup.objects.\
                                                filter(company=instance.company, hidden=False).\
                                                order_by('group_name')
```

View (the create part works, not the update, but it did work):

```py
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser or (u.id is not None and u.usercomp.is_admin))
def adm_event_detail(request, comp_slug, evt_id=0):
    '''
        Manage events creation and options
    '''
    company = Company.get_company(request.session['comp_slug'])
    # all_groups = list(UserGroup.objects.filter(company=company, hidden=False).order_by('group_name').values())

    if evt_id > 0:
        current_event = Event.objects.get(id=evt_id)
        event_form = EventDetail(request.POST or None, instance=current_event)

    else:
        event_form = EventDetail(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if event_form.is_valid():
            if evt_id == 0:
                # Create new event
                event_data = {
                    "company": company,
                    "groups": event_form.cleaned_data["groups"],
                    "event_name": event_form.cleaned_data["event_name"],
                    "event_date": event_form.cleaned_data["event_date"],
                    "quorum": event_form.cleaned_data["quorum"],
                    "rule":event_form.cleaned_data["rule"]
                }
                new_event = Event.create_event(event_data)
            else:
                new_event = event_form.save()

        else:
            print("****** FORMULAIRE NON VALIDE *******")
            print(event_form.errors)

    return render(request, "polls/adm_event_detail.html", locals())
```

HTML (extract):

```html
{% if evt_id %}
<form action="{% url 'polls:adm_event_detail' company.comp_slug evt_id %}" method="post">
{% else %}
<form action="{% url 'polls:adm_create_event' company.comp_slug %}" method="post">
{% endif %}
    {% csrf_token %}

    <p>Sélectionnez le(s) groupe(s) d'utilisateurs participants à l'événement :</p>
    <ul style="list-style-type: none">
    {% for grp in event_form.groups %}
        <li>{{ grp }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</form>
```

The related display (Group 1 box should be checked):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit disappointed there was not at least a comment, but I finally found how to deal with all of this and will share it here.
First, I needed to move all stuff in the vie, so the form become very simple:

```py
class EventDetail(forms.ModelForm):
    groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label = "Liste des groupes",
        queryset = None,
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required = False
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['event_name', 'event_date', 'quorum', 'rule']
```

To manage create and update values, the key points are the following:

- I just understood that model based vs no model is not equivalent to queryset vs initial, in terms of form creation. I can guess that for many of you it's obvious, but for me it was not yet! Thus, I actually needed both to have a right display: `queryset` attribute will display the whole list, `initial` will check the ones that are linked to my object
- `save()` method is not enough when a field is linked to an M2M relationship. I understood from [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) (but I was obviously wrong!) that it would be enough, but I have to manage this filed separately. It basically means to things: add the values in the new form, and do not forget to remove those that the users do not want to be linked anymore.

Thus, here is my final working views:

```py
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser or (u.id is not None and u.usercomp.is_admin))
def adm_event_detail(request, comp_slug, evt_id=0):
    company = Company.get_company(comp_slug)

    if evt_id > 0:
        current_event = Event.objects.get(id=evt_id)
        event_form = EventDetail(request.POST or None, instance=current_event)
        event_form.fields['groups'].initial= current_event.groups.all()

    else:
        event_form = EventDetail(request.POST or None)
        # question_set = QuestionFormset()

    event_form.fields['groups'].queryset= UserGroup.objects.\
                                            filter(company=company, hidden=False).\
                                            order_by('group_name')
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if event_form.is_valid():
            if evt_id == 0:
                # Create new event
                event_data = {
                    "company": company,
                    "groups": event_form.cleaned_data["groups"],
                    "event_name": event_form.cleaned_data["event_name"],
                    "event_date": event_form.cleaned_data["event_date"],
                    "quorum": event_form.cleaned_data["quorum"],
                    "rule":event_form.cleaned_data["rule"]
                }
                new_event = Event.create_event(event_data)
            else:
                new_event = event_form.save()
                new_event.groups.clear()
                new_event = event_form.save()
                new_event.groups.add(*event_form.cleaned_data['groups'])

        else:
            print("****** FORMULAIRE NON VALIDE *******")
            print(event_form.errors)

    return render(request, "polls/adm_event_detail.html", locals())
```

If a simpler approach exists, I would really appreciate to know =)

To provide with a complete answer, I also changed the template and used only one line:

```html
    {{ event_form.groups }}
```

and a dedicated CSS property to hide list's bullets:

```css
#id_groups {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```